# Arcanist How To Checkout to Specific ID

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I'm using phabricator and I see this in my diff in the web app

```
DIFF | ID |Base
DIFF 30 | 41275 | xyz123
DIFF 31 | 41276 | xyz123
```

Is there way for me to `checkout` to what my code as at `DIFF 30`

Answer (score 1):

To apply diff on your local branch, you may consider

```
arc patch <your diff ID>
```

ref: https://gist.github.com/tony612/f698465a5c74b3cd6d98

Answer (score 0):

found it:

`git checkout phabricator/diff/41275`

each `arc diff` applies a tag.